# Access Query -- I want either "Yes," or "No," but keep getting both?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In my database, I have a Yes/No field for "Active," and I have built a form to fill out search criteria.

On the form, I have a checkbox called chkActive (normal 2-state checkbox, defaulting to True).  In the query, I have a critera of:

`IIf([Forms]![Criteria_Form]![chkActive]=True,True,False)`

If I check chkActive, I get all the Active results.  If I don't check chkActive, I get everything in my database, regardless of whether it's Active or not.  If I change the criteria to simply True or False, I get exactly what I want.

Is there some way to tell my query I only want the False records when chkActive IS NOT checked?

Comment: Using your `IIf` statement and `chkActive` is set to **False**.  Do you get everything or just the records where it is `NULL` or `False`?

Comment: Need to see how you're using the `IIf` statement in your query.

Comment: Please provide the whole criteria (from the sql view).

Comment: paulroho, thanks -- there were a bunch of OR [Forms]![Criteria_Form]![chkActive]=False lines after that criteria.